# Using sed to replace some lower case letters to upper case

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to replace _[lowercase] to [uppercase] using sed in bash.

So far I've tried this code:

```
new_arr=$( echo $old_arr | sed -e 's%_\(.\)%\1\U%g' )
```

With input of

```
this_is_a_function()
```

i expected the output to be

```
thisIsAFunction()
```

but i got

```
thisisafunction
```

Do you have a suggestion for what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: You swapped the placeholder and the uppercase operator, use `sed -e 's%_\(.\)%\U\1%g'`

Comment: The hard way would be not to use sed, and just loop through the characters in each word, and if _ is found, send the next character to a case switch statement mapped for each lower case alphabet letter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
sed 's/_\([a-z]\)/\U\1/g'  Input_file
```

---

---

So in OP's case it should be something like:

```
new_arr=$( echo "$old_arr" | sed 's%_\([a-z]\)%\U\1%g' )
```